# Detecting Vibration on a Table with the iPhone

Tags: ios4, detect, iphone-vibrate

is it possible to detect vibration on the iPhone? I'm trying to figure out how to detect when the user smacks a desk or table when the phone is sitting on it. I remember reading somewhere you could detect a smack on a wooden table using the mic and AVFoundation. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: might want to think about going through your past questions and clicking the checkmark next to the best answer to accept it.  you could check the accelerometer for a sharp change or the mic for sudden noise. I'm curious as to what you would use this for?

Comment: Thanks! Going through my past questions now. What I'm trying to do is create a custom looking Music app and well, i'm not sure if you remember the show "Happy Days" and "The Fonz" how he would hit the juke box to start/stop the music. Well i'm trying to achieve that same effect to play/pause the music similar to what he did. Not sure if this app will actually make it to the App Store but I'd like to go forward with the idea.

Comment: could be an interesting learning experience, but would almost definitely not get into the appstore(apple may fear damage to the device), an alternative would be to get it to respond to a shake gesture, or if it is in a quiet enough environment, your fingers clicking.

Comment: I've thought of a shake as well, just haven't seemed to get the UIAccelerometer to be sensitive enough to pick up a vibration. As for the snapping of the fingers. I haven't really tried but it seemed the mic was too sensitive or not sensitive enough to pick it up. I'll mess with the snapping fingers solution. You don't happen to have any sites where I could find the an example to make the UIAccelerometer really sedative? Thanks

Comment: there used to be some apple sample code, which used a high-pass filter. there was also some samplecode that would draw a graph on the screen from the accelerometer, maybe worth finding that to see if the iphone is picking up any vibration at all.

Comment: Good point. I'll search around for that. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever find a good non-microphone solution? I am looking exactly for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go down the microphone route, something like this might do the trick:

```
//somewhere during setup call this line
[anAVAudioRecorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];

//then in a method used to poll the audioMeter
[anAVAudioRecorder updateMeters];
averagePower = [anAVAudioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
if (averagePower > threshold ) {
    [musicPlayerClass play];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with that :)

Comment: when vibrate AVAudioRecorder can not recod